# Using ehcache in a dropwizard project

Tags: java, ehcache, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard to create a RESTful service. To avoid hammering the database, I am looking for a good caching solution in java. Searching the web lead me to ehcache. I have read the documentation a bit, but currently it is not clear to me how to use ehcache in a dropwizard project.

For instance, where does the configuration file go? I just need something to help me start using the cache.

If this is difficult to integrate, what would be the most suited caching solution for dropwizard project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ultimately want a simpler (than ehcache) cache framework/API, consider using CacheBuidler from guava:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

A typical cache implementation and use requires just a few lines of code and no configuration files.

Comment: I did a quick browse, and this looks like a good fit for my need. I'll try to implement a quick one, and let you know of the the result. Thanks!

Comment: @Erwin Here's an example of it in use in a simple Dropwizard based blog: https://github.com/jim618/multibit-website/tree/master/src/main/java/org/multibit/site/caches

Comment: @GaryRowe Thanks for the sample code. This will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I have been able to set it up. Here's how.

1. Get the `hibernate` version. You can get this from the dependencies of `dropwizard-hibernate` package. eg. `dropwizard-hibernate:1.3.12` depends on `hibernate-core:5.2.18.Final`.
2. Add ehcache matching the exact version of hibernate, so in this case `compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.2.18.Final'`
3. Enable 2nd level caching on hibernate. Dropwizard manages configuration in config.yml. So this would be something like:

```
# For documentation on available options please refer io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory
database:
  # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
  properties:
    # Enable second level cache with EhCache
    hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
    hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

4. Now, your cache should be enabled. You can now use annotations on entities to make them cacheable. see doc on `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`

I found this article to be a good start. https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache. There are also other types of caches like query cache etc which may help depending on your use case.